# Is the hypothesis of this problem enough to prove it? Universal property of localization

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, localization, universal-property

I was recently given the following two-part problem on a homework assignment. To be clear from the start, I am not asking for a solution to the problem (I like to solve my own homework problems!) - but I believe that part (2) is incorrectly stated. Particularly I think the hypothesis needs to be stronger to get the desired result. My Question is: is my hypothesis true that, as stated, it is not enough to reach the desired claim.

The question reads:

> a) Prove that if $\phi \colon R \to S$ is a ring homomorphism and $\phi(f)$ is a unit in $S$ then there is a unique ring homomorphism $\psi \colon R[t]/ \langle tf-1 \rangle \to S$ such that $\psi \circ i = \phi$ where $i$ is the natural embedding of $R$ into $R[t]/ \langle tf-1 \rangle$.
>
> b)Prove that if $Q$ is any ring with the above property then $Q$ is isomorphic to $R[t]/ \langle tf-1 \rangle$.

As many of you will likely recognize, yes, this is leading towards proving the "Rabinowitz Trick".

I have successfully finished part a) and I know how the argument $\textit{should}$ go for part b) only because I am familiar with localization and the ring $R[t]/\langle tf-1 \rangle$ is just the localization $R_f$ in disguise, and I am familiar with the universal property that characterizes localizations, but as stated I don't think we have enough to prove the isomorphism. Perhaps because 'if $Q$ has the above property' is somewhat vague, but I already asked my professor once and he seemed confident I should be successful in applying the standard argument where I have compositions giving $Q \to Q$ and $R_f \to R_f$ both being the identity thus granting a unique isomorphism between them.

I am only posting here because I don't want to bother emailing my professor again unless I am sure there is a flaw in the problem statement. But I think we need to add the clause that the ring $Q$ comes with a morphism, say $j \colon R \to Q$ such that $j(f)$ is also a unit in $Q$

Comment: I think the problem implicitly assumes you have a map $R \to Q$, otherwise the phrase "$Q$ is any ring with the above property" doesn't make any sense

Comment: I agree, and when I talked to him he did say that $Q$ comes with the map $R \to Q$, but my thought was that we would need to know that map carries $f$ to a unit in $Q$ also

Comment: In general are you dealing with $R$-algebras?

Comment: For the scope of this class just rings

Comment: When I learned this we were taught that the localization of a ring is the initial object in the category of $R$-algebras $i:R \to S$ such that $i$ sends every element of the localizing set to a unit. In particular this means a map $i$ must exist, and that it sends $f$ to a unit, as you say

Comment: I guess this question is technically resolved - I emailed him again and we both agreed that the condition that Q come with a map R --> Q that carries f to a unit was the correct hypothesis.